# How to turn globbing on and off?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards, alias, bashrc

Within my `~./bashrc` in an alias I have turned of globbing like this.

```
alias x='set -f;. any.sh'
```

But which command enables globbing again or should I set this options in `any.sh`?

Any response is welcome.

Comment: maybe `set -f && any.sh && set +f` ...?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Actually I wrote to the end of `any.sh` the command `set +f` and it works. Are there different issues in your or my approach?

Comment: Same result , different approach. In my approach commands are chained by `&&` which means that the exit code of previous command must be "success" = "0" for the next command to run. By your approach `set +f` can be present anywhere in your script. You can re-enable globbing at will , even if the any.sh script will finally "fail".

Comment: @JohnGoofy: Please **edit your question** to motivate it. *Why do you want to disable globbing*? Can't you use something different than a Posix shell (e.g. Python, Awk, [scsh](https://scsh.net/), ....) ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I figured out, that your approach won't work for me. I left my alias as posted and added `set +f` to the end of `any.sh`.

Comment: In any case, `set -f; any.sh; set +f` or `set -f && any.sh && set +f` don't make much sense as there's no glob to be expanded in between that `set -f` and that `set +f`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know, I tried this before I asked my question.

Comment: Why would someone want to switch something on after some work if it would be better to simply return back to state which was there before. By going further I propose to simply make that option change local for that specific task. Encapsulation at its best. As for me the simplest way to achieve that is to use a `subshell`. Just put a part of script in brackets and all options changes which happen inside will be discarded after it. For example: `alias x='( set -f;. any.sh ; )'`.

Comment: Ah, the eternal struggle against globbing. I have been battling it for my entire career.

this is what I use to feed e.g. `git branch`:

```
PATTERN=`echo $PATTERN --list *$1*`
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want globs to be disabled only while the shell is interpreting code in `any.sh`, with `bash4.4+` or `ash`-based shells, you can do:

```
x() {
  local -
  set -o noglob
  . any.sh
}
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
x() {
  set -o localoptions -o noglob
  . any.sh
}
```

That is use a function instead of an alias (you don't want to use aliases for several commands as that doesn't do what you want when you do `cmd | x` or `cmd && x` for instance), make sure changes to options (to the `$-` variable as one way to look at it) are local to the function, disable glob and source the file.

With older versions of `bash`, you could do:

```
x() {
  local ret restore
  [[ $- = *f* ]] || restore='set +o noglob'
  set -o noglob
  . any.sh
  ret=$?
  eval "$restore"
  return "$ret"
}
```

Or maybe a more generic helper function like:

```
withopt() {
  local ret option
  local -a restore
  option=$1; shift
  [[ -o $option ]] || restore=(set +o "$option")

  set -o "$option"
  "$@"
  ret=$?
  "${restore[@]}"
  return "$ret"
}
```

And then, you can use an alias if you like like:

```
alias x='withopt noglob . any.sh'
```

Note that it doesn't prevent `*` from being expanded if you do:

```
x *
```

As the `noglob` option ends up being enabled long after that command has been evaluated. For that, see [my other answer](/a/388697) (an answer to a different question).

Comment: Dear fellow. I already have an easy and short solution. I prepend `set -f` to my alias and I put `set +f` to my script and It works. Are there some issues to use your approach? If not, I don't know if I should close, delete or answer my self this question.

Comment: @JohnGoofy, why don't you add `set -f` to your script if it's your script that need glob disabled? I'm not sure I understand your use case.

Comment: I wrote a little file manager for the CLI. Because there are wildcards I need both, globbing and not globbing within one task and of course after executing the script I want globbing again.

Comment: @JohnGoofy: Normally you should just write your script to quote anything that you don't want glob-expansion to act on.  e.g. `"$foo"` instead of `$foo`

Comment: Can I disable globbing only for find command? Example instead of doing `set -f; find . -name *.cpp; set+f` only do `find . -name *.cpp`

Comment: @Sergio, there, you only need to quote that `*` shell wildcard operator: `find . -name '*.cpp'` Or `find . -name '[*].cpp'` if you want to find a file called literally `*.cpp`.

Answer (score 5):

> This was posted before the question was clarified, and now addresses a different need. I'm still leaving it here as that can be useful to others.

I suppose you want to be able to do:

```
x *.txt
```

and the `*.txt` to be passed unexpanded to `any.sh` and globs to be reenabled afterwards.

You can't do that with `bash`. Use `zsh` instead where you can do:

```
alias x='noglob any.sh`
```

Where `noglob` disables aliases only for that command.

```
$ echo /etc/p*d
/etc/pam.d /etc/passwd /etc/profile.d
$ noglob echo /etc/p*d
/etc/p*d
```

Note that it affects the expansion of globs in arguments of that `echo` commands only. `*` would still be expanded in `noglob echo $(echo *)` or `noglob eval 'echo *'` or `noglob . some-script` where `some-script` does a `echo *`.

Actually, there may be a way with `bash`:

```
oneshot_noglob() {
  case $- in
    (*f*) ;; # globs already disabled
    (*) set -f; shot=0; debug_trap=$(trap -p DEBUG)
        trap '
          if ((++shot == 2)); then
            set +f
            trap - DEBUG
            '"$debug_trap"'
          fi' DEBUG;;
  esac
}

alias x='oneshot_noglob; any.sh'
```

Which uses the DEBUG trap to restore `set +f` after one command has been executed after the `set -f`.

Now, with all aliases that contain more than one command, that has a few caveats.

```
echo foo | x
```

Becomes:

```
echo foo | oneshort_noglob; any.sh
```

So the output of `echo` is only fed to `oneshort_noglob`.

Same for things like:

```
cmd && x
```

Where `any.sh` would be executed regardless of whether `cmd` is successful or not.

Also note that it affects all globs in every level of subshell until just before the second command is being executed in the main shell process.

For instance, in `x $(echo *; echo *) *`, none of those `*` would be expanded because the DEBUG trap is not inherited unless you set the `extdebug` option.

Comment: I have made an edit to my alias. I forgot the source `.`. I have tried your approach with and without `source`. However, if my alias looks Iike I have posted and I write to the end of my script `set +f` I can pass wildcard arguments and my bash is still able for globbing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. But I have found a solution, just appending `set +f` to my file and it works.

Comment: By the way, even without the `.` in my alias, your approach won't work for me as I mentioned.

Comment: @JohnGoofy, as I said, that's to be able to call `any.sh *` with a litteral argument passed to `any.sh` as that's the only way I could make sense of your question before you added the `.`. It doesn't answer your question now that you've clarified it.

Comment: `(f)` does not match a word which consists of more than `f`. You need `*f*`

Answer (score 1):

One may change something temporarily and then try to return it back to the state it was before. But I propose better, cleaner, more reliable and better maintainable approach: **just make needed change local**.
`Bash` allows you to easily achieve that by using a ***subshell*** (more info here - [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)).

In your case it can be done like this

```
alias x='( set -f;. any.sh ; )'
```

Comment: @roaima, if OP used `.` (`source`) command as an optimization to avoid spawning another shell subprocess then yes, subshell is not an answer. But it is also worth mentioning that this kind of performance degradation can be noticed in cases like calling scripts in a loop or similar. If user start this from command line by issuing explicit command manually then the performance degradation should be neglectible. Taking into account that this is an alias I assumed that OP plans to call it manually. I may be wrong.

Comment: @roaima and thank you for bringing up concerns. Those are really valid in some cases. And it also turned into some elaboration from my side which I forgot (was lazy) to add initially.

Comment: (1) I don’t see any comments by roaima, so I don’t know what he said.  But you haven’t edited your answer, so I’ll pick up where he left off.  As far as I’m concerned, the #1 reason for activating a script by sourcing it rather than running it (by fork&exec) is that the script modifies the shell’s environment: changing directory, setting/modifying shell variables and options, establishing/modifying signal traps, changing per-process kernel settings like umask and limits, etc.  Sourcing the script *from within an explicit subshell **completely*** precludes any such capability.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) I have voted to close the question as “Needs detail or clarity” for lack of explanation of what the OP is doing and wants to do.  Lacking such explanation, we should bear in mind that, if you say `alias x='` *`cmd₁`* `;` *`cmd₂`* `'`, and then you say `x ` *`arg₁ arg₂`*, it expands as *`cmd₁`* `;` *``cmd₂ arg₁ arg₂``*.  With your answer, if the user says `x ` *`arg₁ arg₂`*, the arguments do not get passed to `any.sh`. (3) BTW, you don’t need to have a `;` at the end of a list of commands in parentheses.  And it’s traditional to put spaces *after* semicolons and not before them.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get glob to work in bash shell script after trying several settings.
Instead, I put a glob in my CLI, and that worked as expected.

Since this didn't work:
`sh ./test.sh file
ls "${1}*.ppm"`

Replaced it with:
`sh ./test.sh file f*.ppm
ls ${2}`

Not a direct answer to the question, but a helpful alternative approach for a similar situation.

Comment: (1) If you have a “bash shell script” called `foobar.sh` but you run it with `sh foobar.sh`, then it isn’t 100% a bash shell script any more. (2) Giving scripts names ending with `.sh` is discouraged. (3) You may have a situation similar to the one in this question, but I can’t tell what your situation is, and I can’t see what you’re suggesting, or how it would be helpful to anybody.  If you believe that you have a unique situation and a solution for it, please [post a new question](/questions/ask) and post an answer there. Be sure to include enough information to make your posts intelligible.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Could you explain more on "(2) Giving scripts names ending with .sh is discouraged."? Or do you have any reference on that?. Thanks

Comment: Well, feelings / opinions are more divided than I had remembered, but see [File extensions for Unix shell scripts](/q/31760/80216), [Use `.sh` or ``.bash`` extension for bash scripts?](/q/182882/80216), [Should I save my scripts with the `.sh` extension?](https://askubuntu.com/q/503127/325633), [`.sh` specifying extension?](https://askubuntu.com/q/764121/325633), [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful (Command names should never have filename extensions)](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and [Greg's Wiki – Full Bash Guide / Scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide#BashGuide.2FCommandsAndArguments.line-203). Also, if you hang around Unix & Linux Stack Exchange long enough, you’ll see plenty of posts like this one, where a question-asker or answerer uses a ```.sh``` extension, and somebody makes a comment like mine.